# Laravel Blade not loading jquery validate as intended

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm trying to validate my form to show errors by my validation rules. I'm using blade template with laravel 5.2. Here's my code

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#loginForm').validate({
        rules : {
            email : {
                required : true,
                email : true
            },
            password : {
                required : true
            }
        },
        messages : {
            email : {
                required : '<span class="alert-danger">Email is a required field.</span>',
                email : '<span class="alert-danger">Please enter a valid Email.</span>'
            },
            password : {
                required : '<span class="alert-danger">Password is a required field.</span>'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<html><head>
 <title>Laravel</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

 <link href="http://etl.local/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link href="http://etl.local/assets/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mirza" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
 <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only toggle_nav">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   </button>
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Eric's Tech List</a>
  </div>
   </div> <!-- end of nav container-->
</nav> <!-- End of nav-->
<div class="modal fade" id="login_modal" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Login</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="well">
       <form id="loginForm" method="POST" action="./handleLogin" novalidate="novalidate" role="form">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="yvXKRQ5C15cxBpL6Y186vf9aeEZZxm8UVNxI1kt4">
        <div class="form-group">
         <label for="email" class="control-label">Email/Username</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="" required="" placeholder="Please enter your email" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Please enter your email'" onfocus="this.placeholder= ''" aria-required="true">
         <span class="help-block"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
         <label for="password" class="control-label">Password</label>
         <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" value="" required="" placeholder="Please enter your password" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Please enter your password'" onfocus="this.placeholder= ''" aria-required="true">
         <span class="help-block"></span>
        </div>
        <div id="loginMsg"></div>
        <div class="checkbox">
         <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember"> Remember login
         </label>
         <p class="help-block">(if this is a private computer)</p>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Login</button>
        <a href="/forgot/" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Help to login</a>
       </form>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-6">
      <p class="lead">Register now for <span class="text-success">FREE</span></p>
      <ul class="list-unstyled" style="line-height: 2">
       <li><span class="fa fa-check text-success"></span> See all your orders</li>
       <li><span class="fa fa-check text-success"></span> Fast re-order</li>
       <li><span class="fa fa-check text-success"></span> Save your favorites</li>
       <li><span class="fa fa-check text-success"></span> Fast checkout</li>
       <li><span class="fa fa-check text-success"></span> Get a gift <small>(only new customers)</small></li>
       <li><a href="/read-more/"><u>Read more</u></a></li>
      </ul>
      <p><a href="http://etl.local/register" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Yes please, register now!</a></p>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div> <!-- End of modal-->
<div class="container">
  <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="POST" id="loginForm">
  <fieldset>
   <div id="legend">
    <legend class="">Register</legend>
   </div>
   <div class="control-group">
    <!-- Username -->
    <label class="control-label" for="username">Email</label>
    <div class="controls">
     <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge">
     <p class="help-block"></p>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="control-group">
    <!-- Password-->
    <label class="control-label" for="password">Password</label>
    <div class="controls">
     <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge">
     <p class="help-block">Password should be at least 4 characters</p>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="control-group">
    <!-- Password -->
    <label class="control-label" for="password_confirm">Password (Confirm)</label>
    <div class="controls">
     <input type="password" id="password_confirm" name="password_confirm" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge">
     <p class="help-block">Please confirm password</p>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="control-group">
    <!-- Button -->
    <div class="controls">
     <button class="btn btn-success">Register</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </fieldset>
 </form>
</div>
<footer class="footer">
 <div class="container">
  <p>Copyright © ericstechlist.com <script> document.write(new Date().getFullYear())</script>2016 All Rights Reserved</p>
 </div>
</footer>
<script src="http://etl.local/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="http://etl.local/assets/js/app.js"></script>
<script src="http://etl.local/assets/js/login-submit-auth.js"></script>



</body></html>
```

I have a login in the master and it work's fine, but I can't seem to get the login page to work as expected. Jquery is being loaded no errors but validation is not working.

Comment: Please do not use the Code Snippets feature for anything that cannot be run within this SO page.  It's only intended for self-contained JavaScript/HTML/CSS demos.... not PHP or server-side code.  Thanks.  Edited.

Comment: jQuery/JavaScript does not care about your server-side framework.  JavaScript only cares that you generate the relevant and correct HTML markup.  That being said, use your browser to inspect the ***rendered*** HTML code and post that here instead of your PHP.  Also use your browser's JavaScript console to look for errors.

Comment: Otherwise, the code you've posted here is working:  http://jsfiddle.net/5mmyq7c0/  ~ You're going to have to inspect your ***rendered*** HTML markup, and check your JavaScript console for errors.  Perhaps your file includes are broken... if that's the case, we can't see that here either.

Comment: I looked in console it's not throwing any errors. When I try to go to each javascript file from view source it goes to the source of that file. Not really understanding why it's not working here, but works on the login in my master file with the same input fields and form with same id

Comment: Do you have two `<form></form>` containers on the same page using the same `id`?

Comment: I do let me see if that's the problem and if so you're man.

Comment: Posting my answer now.

Comment: You are the man thank you so much that was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are showing two different `<form></form>` containers on the same page, both are using the same `id="loginForm"`.

You absolutely cannot have a duplicate `id` on the same page... it's invalid HTML and will cause JavaScript issues since the second instance is usually ignored.

If you change them to a `class`, you can then have duplicates.  HOWEVER, the jQuery Validate plugin will not like that... when it's declared on multiple `form`'s, only the *first* match is initialized.

There is a workaround...

With `class="loginForm"` on both `form` containers, use a jQuery `.each()` to declare `.validate()` on all instances.

```
$('.loginForm').each(function() {
    $(this).validate({
        .....
    });
});
```